# How can I tell whether a build is Debian-based?

Tags: debian, distributions

I'm starting to work with a box that has a custom (small) Linux build on it. How can I tell whether this is a Debian or Red Hat-based build?

This is what I know so far:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.31-2.5 (build@build-desktop) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Broadcom stbgcc-4.4.3-1.2) ) #7

$ apt-get
-sh: apt-get: command not found

$ yum
-sh: yum: command not found
```

Comment: why `lsb_release -i 2> /dev/null | sed 's/:\t/:/' | cut -d ':' -f 2-` ??

Just run `lsb_release -si`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `uname -a` should give you some general information about the system. Also, you can run `apropos "package manager"` or with similar keywords to hopefully find out more about the package manager. Look in `/etc` for a file named `xyz-release` where `xyz` should be whatever distro is running.

Comment: This is what I get when I run uname -a: $ uname -a
Linux 10.0.1.46 2.6.31-2.5 #7 Thu Dec 15 19:57:09 CST 2011 mips GNU/Linux

Comment: @Sparky1 Then, it seems you have gotten yourself a [Linux-MIPS](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Main_Page) distribution.

Answer (score 14):

For testing for Debian systems,
you can check whether `/etc/debian_version` exists:

```
if [ -f "/etc/debian_version" ]; then
   # do stuff
fi
```

It should be included in Debian
and systems based on it (including Ubuntu and its derivatives),
though a few may not have it —
in this case, you can check all `/etc/*release` files:

```
if [ "$(grep -Ei 'debian|buntu|mint' /etc/*release)" ]; then
   # do stuff
fi
```

Where `debian|buntu|mint` is a list of distribution names
to look for (not case sensitively) —
you can get an idea of some common derivatives from [here](https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros),
though Debian derivatives like Ubuntu
[have their own derivatives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives).

---

For RedHat based systems, the derivatives use a larger range of files,
and might not have `lsb-release` installed —
so you can apply the following methods:

- get the release name from

  ```
   lsb_release -i 2> /dev/null | sed 's/:\t/:/' | cut -d ':' -f 2-
  ```
- check the DISTRIB-ID in the `lsb-release` file —
  a fallback method that is probably unnecessary on modern systems,
  also, the file apparently is missing on Fedora,
  and does not contain DISTRIB_ID on OpenSUSE
- check for the existence of some of the following

  - `/etc/fedora-release` and/or `/etc/redhat-release`
    for Fedora or RedHat, respectively
  - `/etc/SuSE-release` for SuSe
  - `/etc/mandriva-release` for mandriva/mageia
- use a similar method to the latter Debian one:

  ```
   if [ "$(grep -Ei 'fedora|redhat' /etc/*release)" ]; then
   ...
  ```

The first 3 points I sourced from the update cron of Google Chrome,
so you could examine that to find out more
(it also determines package managers).

---

For a wider range of OSs, ["How to detect the OS from a Bash script?" [on Stack Overflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792848/2943276)
should help.

Answer (score 3):

Check output of:

```
lsb_release -a
```

and:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

You can also check for more low-lever package commands `rpm` for RedHat and `dpkg` for Debian.

Comment: $ dpkg  
command not found

$ rpm 
(shows options for the rpm command).
 
Looks like this a red hat based build. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can also check _/etc/debian_version_ file, which exists in all debian based linux distribution

Comment: Also install it using `apt-get install lsb-release` if it's not installed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an embedded device (e.g. a SoHo router), it probably won't be any of the "desktop/server" distros. I'd try to look into the device's manual, manufacturer's website (should have source to the GPL-licensed code), and the Web at large.

Answer (score 0):

`uname -a` and `cat /proc/version` (*read-only for superusers*), in my honest opinion, are the only correct answers to this question as the rest - like `lsb_release`, `/etc/issue` or `cat /proc/sys/kernel/version` - are not available/not usable on every system (not even official Debian distros). Also don't bother using `/etc/*releases`, `/etc/*version` since they can be altered. The latter is not available on all Debian distros.

Other options could be (not my recommendation):

- Check for `dash` or verify if `sh` is linked to `dash` (it should be the default for running scripts)
- Check the package manager by executing `>/dev/null 2>&1 dpkg --version && { ... }`

Comment: `uname -a` and `cat /proc/version` provide information on the executing kernel. So e.g. within a container (e.g. Docker, lxc, etc.), these commands show information about the container's **host** distribution. The host may be different from the container (e.g. host is Debian, container is Arch).