# How to determine in a shell script whether the distribution I am on is Debian-based?

Tags: debian, distributions

I have been writing a shell script that needs to know if the system one is on is, in fact, Debian-based. Now I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29981/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-build-is-debian-based) question, but its answers weren't so helpful. I am aware of checking `/etc/os-release` and the output of `lsb_release`, likewise I know that checking if `rpm` or `dpkg` commands exist is another way of checking whether one's distribution is Red Hat or Debian-based, respectively. All these methods have flaws though. There are hundreds of different Debian-based distros (including those based on Ubuntu, which is in itself based on Debian) and checking whether the `NAME` field in `/etc/os-release`, or the `Distributor ID` in the output of `lsb_release -a` matches any of the hundreds of known Debian-based distributions would take forever. Checking whether the commands dpkg and rpm exist aren't fool-proof either as some people install other distribution's package managers for various different reasons. For example, on my Ubuntu machine I have RPM installed, partly because sometimes I use the Open Build Service's OSC command, which in some cases requires RPM.

So in short I want a simple and fast way of checking (with certainty) whether the distribution my script finds itself on is Debian-based or not.  Is this possible?

**EDIT**: As people seem to be implying, by voting to close this question, that /etc/debian_version is present on all Debian-based systems. Does anyone have proof of this?

Comment: I never even referred to `/etc/debian_version` so I don't see how this could be a duplicate.

Comment: Although titled a little differently, [Does Linux Mint have /etc/debian_version?](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182409) provides two reliable solutions to check if a system is indeed Debian-based. It's not a "duplicate" of your question, but it answers your question, which is another possible reason for a "duplicate" close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Debian derivatives should have `/etc/debian_version`, which is provided by the essential [`base-files`](https://tracker.debian.org/base-files) package. Since it's essential you can rely on it being installed, and therefore the file being present.

I say "should" because there's nothing preventing a derivative from deleting that file, but as far as I'm aware none do. See [Does Linux Mint have /etc/debian_version?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182409/does-linux-mint-have-etc-debian-version) for more details.